# How to make a div group's background colour wider?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-color

I want the background colour of a div to extend past the minimum dimensions. Say 10px more in each direction.

Using flexBox and I have the following result: https://gyazo.com/815fcc78086c81cdc46b758c9230e9b9

My attempt is to add a border to the div, and then make that the same colour to simulate an extension. See where I have border property? That's the attempt.

```
.volunteer, .organization {
    display: flex;
    color: rgb(193,193,193);
    background-color: rgba(1,48,87,.9);
    border: 15px, solid, rgba(255,48,87,.9);
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 5%;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Only other way I see to do this is by making a background in photoshop but that seems so extra.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `padding: 10px;` instead? Otherwise just remove the commas from your `border` so it's `border: 15px solid rgba(255,48,87,.9);`

Comment: @MichaelCoker amazing tyvm, didnt know the commas were a problem. padding also worked tyvm : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `padding`. You can simply add this line:

```
padding: 10px;
```

and adjust the number to what you want.

Comment: perfect tyvm. Also apparently my commas were causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just try adding the `padding`

```
padding 5px;
```

or any number that you like